# Why display Price zero some items, but others are ok

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I'm new for magento. I'm in trouble with product prices and categories.See snapshot i post. some item's price shown zero. Why so that? Can anybody guess?what are the configs I have missed.
[image]

Comment: is first one is configurable product and other 2 is simple ?

Comment: Thank you Pawan. Yes it is..  So , what should i do for convert it? re-export products as simple?

Comment: are you used your custom product collection?

Comment: Hi, sorry ,what do you mean custom product collection? products are loading from distributor database through rewix plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create different configurations for the product. First you have to create an attribute set and add the necessary product attributes (eg. color, size etc.). Then include that attribute set in your product. After that provide a simple price for the product. Then scroll down and click on create configurations. Then select the attributes that you want to create the configuration for. Add images and price for the selected configuration. But beware that you can only add images and price for a single configuration at a time. Then create those products. Now go to your customer view and refresh the page. I hope this helps. I have also attached images for your reference.

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFfXg.jpg) for the images.

Comment: Thank you, Mathanagopal. excellent explanation. I'm using M 1.9 due to client's requirement and can't manage products as u mention ,bcz products are syncing via another party. The zero products are configurable. How can I convert type to simple ?

Comment: You could simply change the product type to Simple Product or provide some default price so that magento can deal with it. Look at step 3 on page 158 in the attached [devdocs](https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/Resources/archive/magento_community_edition_user_guide_v.1.9.pdf). They are choosing the product type to be Configurable Product. You can go to that specific product and simply change that. In point 4 of step 3 it has been mentioned that product price is a required field. Maybe when syncing, the product price may not be available and magento is setting a default of 0 on it's own.

Comment: Hi giys, sorry for delay reply. It has solved after configured all product type as configurable. Thank you all. for your ideas.

Comment: Good to hear it.